# finding not-repeating number

Tags: c, algorithm

I don't really know how to explain it, so I'll explain on my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

// factorial source : http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-program-find-factorial
int factorial(int n)
{
  int c, fact = 1;

  for (c = 1; c <= n; c++)
    fact = fact * c;
  return fact;
}

int main() {
  int i,j,switch_flag;
  int digit_length = 3;
  int probability = factorial(digit_length);

  unsigned char *digit = malloc(digit_length);

  for (i=0 ; i<digit_length ; i++)
    digit[i] = i;

  // Print Digit
  for (i=0 ; i<digit_length ; i++)
    printf("[%d]",digit[i]);
  printf("\n");


  for (i=1 ; i<probability ; i++) {
    switch_flag = i%(digit_length-1);

    unsigned char temp = digit[switch_flag];
    digit[switch_flag] = digit[switch_flag+1];
    digit[switch_flag+1] = temp;

    // Print Digit
    for (j=0 ; j<digit_length ; j++)
        printf("[%d]",digit[j]);
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output when I set the digit_length to 3 :

```
[0][1][2]
[0][2][1]
[2][0][1]
[2][1][0]
[1][2][0]
[1][0][2]
```

Output when I set the digit_length to 4 :

```
[0][1][2][3]
[0][2][1][3]
[0][2][3][1]
[2][0][3][1]
[2][3][0][1]
[2][3][1][0]
[3][2][1][0]
[3][1][2][0]
[3][1][0][2]
[1][3][0][2]
[1][0][3][2]
[1][0][2][3]
[0][1][2][3]
[0][2][1][3]
[0][2][3][1]
[2][0][3][1]
[2][3][0][1]
[2][3][1][0]
[3][2][1][0]
[3][1][2][0]
[3][1][0][2]
[1][3][0][2]
[1][0][3][2]
[1][0][2][3]
```

The result when digit_length is more than 3 is not as expected
I don't know what keyword I should use to search, so I asked here
Please help me

EDIT :
I have found the answer here :
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/

Comment: What is the unexpected behavior for digit_length more than 3? I see that the result for 4 is correct!

Comment: It doesn't get all of the number combination, for example [0][3][1][2]

Comment: search in this site like this : `[c] permutation`

Answer (score 3):

I don't want to write the whole code out for you, but your best bet here is the following recursive approach. To generate all the permutations of a set S:

1. Iterate over all elements x in S
2. For each one, recursively generate all the permutations of S \ {x}, and attach x to the beginning of them.

In other words, the permutations of {0,1,2,3} are

- 0 followed by each permutation of {1,2,3}
- 1 followed by each permutation of {0,2,3}
- 2 followed by each permutation of {0,1,3}
- 3 followed by each permutation of {0,1,2}

Comment: yes, I know it mathematically, but I don't know the algorithm for it. Would you explain if you don't mind

Comment: @OP, try re-writing `for (i=1 ; i<probability ; i++) { switch_flag = i%(digit_length-1); swap();` as suggested by @chiastic-security and post it.